# Как изменять цвет при наведении на svg?

Tags: html, css

Я начинающий разработчик столкнулась с проблемой.

```
 <li class="nav__icons-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav__icons-link">
                                <img src="img/3d-square 1.svg" alt="Product" class="nav__icons-img">
                                <p href="" class="nav__icons-title">Product</p>
                            </a>
                            <img src="img/chevron-right 2.svg" alt="">
</li>
```

Имеется следующий код. Необходимо реализовать hover, но если с текстом у меня получилось, то с картинками полный провал. Вот так должно выглядеть (картинку прикрепила) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У svg, вставленных через `img`, менять цвет при наведении не получится - нужно вставлять их в разметку прямо кодом (либо как вариант - с `use` и вытянуть из спрайта)

Comment: Либо нужно напрямую загружать SVG, либо скриптом img превращать в SVG, либо использовать 2 картинки, одна по умолчанию невидимая, при наведении появляется, а другая исчезает, либо использовать шрифтовые иконки icomoon - https://icomoon.io/app/#/select